# Find the number of common items in two sequences for repeating items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a pin number guessing game. A random 4 digit pin number is generated and you need to guess the pin number, if you get it wrong then it should tell you how many of the digits you guessed appear in the pin.

For example, if the pin number was 8823 and i guessed 1788, it should tell me that i got two digits correct because 8 is present twice in both. However, it only tells me that one digit is correct as the digits are the same number. If the numbers are different then there isn't a problem, for example if the pin was 1234 and i guessed 3456 then it would say i got two correct because 3 and 4 both appear once and are different numbers.

This is all of the code (i have made the area i believe to contain the problem **bold**):

```
import random
pin=random.randint(1000,9999)
pin2=str(pin)
pin3=list(pin2)
tries=0
x=1
guess="1"
while x==1:
    pin3=list(pin2)
    guess2=int(guess)
    while guess2<1000 or guess2>9999:
        guess2=int(input("Please guess a 4 digit number: "))
        guess=str(guess2)
    tries+=1

    # BEGIN OF INDICTED CODE ============================
    correct=0
    for i, a in enumerate(pin3):
        guess3=list(guess)
        if a in guess:
            del(pin3[i])
            correct+=1
    print("You got", correct, "correct")
    # END OF INDICTED CODE ==============================

    if guess==pin2:
        x=0
    guess="1"
print("You guessed correctly")
print("You had", tries, "attempts")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are mutating the list you are enumerating, `pin3`. All advice is not to do that because it is hard to reason about what happens when you  do. Work with a copy.

Comment: try and print `i` and `a` inside the for loop. you will notice that you are skipping elements, that is because you delete from `pin3` while iterating it.

Comment: Also, as a side comment, you are making copies over copies that you do not really need: `[(i, c) for i, c in enumerate(list('ciao'))]` and `[(i, c) for i, c in enumerate('ciao')]` give the exact same result.

Comment: Note that this is substantially a [mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)) game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `collections.Counter` type, which is kind of like a set that allows duplicate items (also known as a [bag or multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)).

This way, you can do a simple intersection between two counters to find the common elements.  For example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pin1 = Counter('8823')
>>> pin2 = Counter('1788')
>>> common = pin1 & pin2
>>> list(common.elements())
['8', '8']
>>>
```

Taking the length of this list gives you the number of common elements when duplicates are included.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
def get_num_of_common_digits(pin_number, guessed_pin_number):
    pin_number_str = str(pin_number)
    guessed_pin_number_str = str(guessed_pin_number)
    result = 0
    for x in pin_number_str:
        idx = guessed_pin_number_str.find(x)
        if idx != -1:
            guessed_pin_number_str = guessed_pin_number_str[:idx] + guessed_pin_number_str[idx+1:]
            result += 1
    return result


print(get_num_of_common_digits(8823, 1788))
print(get_num_of_common_digits(1234, 3456))
print(get_num_of_common_digits(8823, 5678))
```

output

```
2
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my way of implementing your game

```
from random import randint
```

here we are generating the pin with the list comprehensions, we iterate 4 times and each time we are generating a random number

```
pin = [randint(0,9) for i in range(4)]

print(pin)
continue_game = True
correct = 0
tries = 0
guessed = []
```

in the below while loop, using "map" we are splitting the guess into a list with 4 elements, and then compare each element from the guess_pin list with each element from the pin list. If the element are matching we increasc correct with 1, if not we increase tries with 1.

```
while continue_game:
    guess = str(input("Guess pin: "))
    guess_pin = list(map(int, guess))
    print(guess_pin)
    for y in guess_pin:
        for x in pin:
            if y == x:
                correct += 1
                guessed.append(y)
            else:
                tries += 1
    if correct == 4:
        continue_game = False
    else:
        pass
    print(f"You had guessed {correct} elements, and tried {tries} times")
```

In the end, we check if the correct equals 4, which means we have guessed all the numbers

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```py
def check_matching(
        guess,
        truth):
    remaining = list(truth)
    n = 0
    for x in guess:
        try:
            remaining.remove(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            n += 1
    return n
```

to be used like:

```py
check_matching('8823', '1788')
# 2
check_matching('1234', '3456')
# 2
check_matching('8823', '5678')
# 1
```

This basically relies on the behavior of the `.remove()` method from built-in Python `list`s. Inputs can be `list`, `tuple` or `str`. Hence I'd recommend sticking to strings to avoid adding unnecessary operations.